# Primitive or wrapper for hibernate primary keys

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I've been looking at various hibernate tutorials and samples, for their identity/primary key property, some use a Java primitive type, some uses the wrapper type, that is;

```
 private int id;
```

vs

```
 private Integer id;
```

Why and when would I use one over the other, for the entity key ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From an Hibernate point of view, it doesn't change anything as Hibernate uses the same Hibernate type to represent them.

However, as pointed out by Bytecode Ninja, you can't distinguish the default value of a primitive int `0` from a an assigned `0` while there is no possible ambiguity with a `null` (a `null` id always means a new entity), which is why I prefer to use a nullable wrapper type.

And this is the Hibernate recommendation. From the Reference Documentation:

> #### [4.1.2. Provide an identifier property (optional)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-pojo-identifier)
>
> Cat has a property called id. This
>   property maps to the primary key
>   column of a database table. The
>   property might have been called
>   anything, and its type might have been
>   any primitive type, any primitive
>   "wrapper" type, java.lang.String or
>   java.util.Date. If your legacy
>   database table has composite keys, you
>   can use a user-defined class with
>   properties of these types (see the
>   section on composite identifiers later
>   in the chapter.)
>
> The identifier property is strictly
>   optional. You can leave them off and
>   let Hibernate keep track of object
>   identifiers internally. We do not
>   recommend this, however.
>
> In fact, some functionality is
>   available only to classes that declare
>   an identifier property:
>
> - Transitive reattachment for detached objects (cascade update or cascade
>     merge) - see Section 10.11,
>     “Transitive persistence”
> - Session.saveOrUpdate()
> - Session.merge()
>
> **We recommend** that you declare
>   consistently-named identifier
>   properties on persistent classes and
>   **that you use a nullable (i.e.,
>   non-primitive) type.**

And I actually leverage this in my base class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Transient
    public boolean isNew() {
        return (this.id == null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree If he want to use a primitive type, he also can encapsulate by using an Integer

Comment: But won't it create wrapper objects every time such an entity object is read from DB, ultimately stressing GC? So would it be better to use primitives where we know that the primary key can't be 0?

Comment: This is still the recommendation as of Hibernate 5.1 but it is now in section "2.5.5. Provide identifier attribute(s)"

Answer (score 11):

I prefer using the wrapper types, because otherwise, when we use primitive types, the primary key `id` will be set to `0` by default, and `0` could be the value of an actual `id` column in the corresponding table of the entity, and this can sometimes lead to hard to pinpoint bugs.

But using a wrapper, the default value of `id` will be `null` and a primary key column cannot have a `null` value, thus you can't update an entity that its `id` value is not set with a valid value by your application's logic.

Comment: Is it always necessary to set the id by application logic? Is there no way hibernate can figure out the next id while persisting a new object when using wrapper as primary key?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify your primary key as a primitive or a wrapper. And since usually the avantages of an `Integer` aren't needed, it's best to keep it simple with an `int`.

More info at [oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25221_04/web.1013/b14428/cmp30cfg.htm#BCGDBFFA).