# Best ID datatype for GWT+ JPA

Tags: gwt, jpa

I know, that similar questions are around.
But for my case: I use GWT 2.4 + JPA 2.0 + (MySQL):

Whatis the best data type for my table IDs?

I want to avoid any type conversions in my GWT project.

My desire is easiness, not performance.

Do you advise me to use Wrapper classes i.e long vs. Long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and straightforward choice is `Long`. Prefer to use the wrapper class, so you can set the id to null, before the object is inserted into the DB (see also [Always use primitive object wrappers for JPA @Id instead of primitive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283709/always-use-primitive-object-wrappers-for-jpa-id-instead-of-primitive-type))

If performance is not a high priority, you may consider using UUIDs instead: This makes it a lot easier to put objects into sets and maps - before they are stored on the servers side. For easiness, you could use Strings to store the UUIDs (GWT doesn't support the UUID datatype), though using an UUID-specific datatype would be a lot more efficient in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the wrapper сlass is better than the primitive. Using of object has many advantages. But in my opinion the best choose of type in this situation is class `String`. `Long` is undesirable to use in GWT development because JavaScript doesn't have the concept of a `long`. So recommended to avoid using long if possible. It's emulated on GWT it affects performance.

Comment: Good point. However, the performance impact when used as an object field is probably not very high (if you don't have an extreme number of objects on the client side). A situation where the "emulated long" effect may become really significant, is when you do lots of math with longs.