# What should be the data type of for id?

Tags: java, types, int, integer, entity

Okay so I have a entity class Person:

```
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;    // -------> Integer or int??                                
    @Column(name = "managerID")
    private  int managerID;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private  String name;
    @Column(name = "externalID")
    private  UUID externalID;


    public Person(long managerID, String name) {
        this.managerID = managerID;
        this.name = name;
        this.externalID = UUID.randomUUID();;
    }
}
```

Ideally what should be the data type for id of an entity, I am using SQL(RDBMS).
Should it be int or Integer? And id Integer, what problems could int give rise to?

Comment: Should it be nullable? I'm asking. And primitive types aren't nullable. Beware though, the JDBC spec requires you to check for `null` with `wasNull`.

Comment: Wow brother !! Don't be rude !! I am new to this and learning stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the primitive `int` type. There should never be a case where that field is null when it is auto-incremented. If it is missing, you can't reference the row with its id using `SELECT ... WHERE id = ...`, therefore not a valid record.

Although primitive types may be an issue where `id` is created without a default value, it will not happen in your column since you auto-incrementing it. **So, if something has a default value or behavior, make it non-nullable; if it does not have a default value or behavior, make it nullable.**

Answer (score 0):

Although primitive type `int` will work, but you should use Object type `Integer` to avoid problems while using any of jpa repositories implementation. Here is one of the issue which you may face [Always use primitive object wrappers for JPA @Id instead of primitive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283709/always-use-primitive-object-wrappers-for-jpa-id-instead-of-primitive-type)