# Spring R2DBC: Save new entity if id is zero

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am migrating from the traditional JPA code base and facing a problem where a new entity cannot be saved by setting id to zero.

Here is my schema (PostreSQL):

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_user (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

In JPA, i can set id to `0` and it will be considered as a new entity. A new id will be assigned automatically.
However in R2DBC, new entities are always saved with id = 0, which is not possible.

I know, I can use `Integer` or `Long` for that and set them `null`, but I am using Kotlin and want to make `id` non-nullable. Otherwise I have to do a huge amount of unnessecary null checks.

```kotlin
userRepo.save(User(0, "A New User")) // works
userRepo.save(User(0, "Another New User")) // error, same id (but works in JPA)
```

```kotlin
@Table("my_user")
data class User(@Id var id: Int = 0,
                var name: String = "")
```

Comment: Why would `0` be considered a new entity by JPA? And why would you need to make null checks for the primary key? You shouldn't be touching that at all in the code.

Comment: @Kayaman because I have to declare id nullable in my Kotlin code like `@Id var id: Int?`. And everytime I access the id, the Kotlin compiler forces me to check if it's null or not.
In JPA, if id is primitive, then zero is considered as new

Comment: But why are you accessing the `id`? It's a database primary key. Your application knows that it's null for new entities and non-null for existing entities, but it shouldn't assign it or access it.

Comment: Because I am dealing with foreign keys. e.g. `postRepo.save(Post(0, user.id, "Some Text"))`. There I am accessing `user.id`

Comment: Seems to be because of different handling between [JPA and Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283709/always-use-primitive-object-wrappers-for-jpa-id-instead-of-primitive-type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this issue will be fixed in Spring Boot 2.4

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/402