# spring boot jpa repository interface always returns null

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, repository

this my code below in my controller even though i pass a key which is valid i always get null as a result.Can someone tell me why is this happening .below is my repository ,controller and domain class

```
public interface AbcRepository extends JpaRepository<ForgotPasswordToken, int> {
    Abc findByHashKey(String hashKey);
    Abc findByUser(User user);
}
```

Mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validateKey/{hashKey}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity validateKey(@PathVariable String hashKey) {
    Abc abc = AbcRepository.findByHashKey(hashKey);
    if (abc == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Invalid key");
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(abc.getUser());
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Abc {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    private String hashKey;

    private String email;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;

    @PrePersist
    public void onCreate() {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your repository is returning `ForgotPasswordToken` not `Abc`, and you key is `long` not `int`

Comment: Or, you don't have any entities matching your criteria

Comment: Hi i tried with long still get the same result . Im using ForgotPasswordToken everywhere instead of Abc.Sorry made a mistake while copying the code here wanted to use alias name for ForgotPasswordToken so used Abc

Comment: i Do have matching entities in my db

Comment: Is `Abc` is null, or your repository is null?

Comment: Hi,Abc is null here .        Abc abc = AbcRepository.findByHashKey(hashKey);
i get null abc

Comment: Are you sure that you have in DB entity with same hashKey?

Comment: hi yes im sure ! i get result when i pass the same query to the db and not here in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different types of primary key in the repository and ABC class.

You should change

```
JpaRepository<ForgotPasswordToken, int>
```

to

```
JpaRepository<ForgotPasswordToken, Long>
```

And use `Long id` in the ABC class

```
private Long id;
```

And it is recommended to use object types as JPA @Id instead of primitives. So change `long` to `Long`.

See [Primitive or wrapper for hibernate primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535791/primitive-or-wrapper-for-hibernate-primary-keys)