# Incorrect JPA entity column type causing issues for FindById

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm currently working on a Spring backend application. We have a `Partner` entity that has the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY` annotation for autogenerating primary keys. The primary key `partnerId` is of type `long`.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "partner_id")
    private long partnerId;
```

In our `Partner` controller class, we wrote some functions for basic CRUD operations. When we make a `post` call to add a Partner, we omit the primary key `partnerId` and include information for the other fields. The post is successful and the data can be seen in the database.

However, when we try to make a `put` call to update the newly added Partner, it instead creates a new Partner entry in the Partner table.

At first, it seemed like a code level issue, but we tested the `put` call on one of the entries that we added to the table from our base data set, it works fine. We used `FindById()` and `isPresent()` to see if an entry exists for this new user with `partnerId` from the incoming Partner object from the `put` call, but got `false`. But with one of the 3 existing Partner entries that we put into the database manually with queries, they returned `true`.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = PATH)
    public ResponseEntity<?> updatePartner(@RequestBody Partner partner) {
        ...
        System.out.println(partnerRepository.findById(partner.getPartnerId()).isPresent());
    }
```

It seems as though the `post` call is setting the new Partner object in the database, but somehow the `partnerId` of any newly posted entry is not of type `long`, which disrupts `findById().isPresent()`. I'm just wondering if anyone knows why this is happening since our entity sets the primary key to type `long` and the controller is sending to the database a `Partner` object.

Comment: Have you checked the database after the post and is the id the same as you use in put?

Comment: Try changing your partnerId type to Long (according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535791/primitive-or-wrapper-for-hibernate-primary-keys accepted answer this is hibrnate recommendation).

Comment: @SimonMartinelli the id of the new entry is not the same as the put, it's as if I made a fresh post call.